# Bind JSON to primitive type action param

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm building an API with ASP.NET Core and I'm having an odd issue with model binding. If I have an action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string foo)
```

And I attempt to post JSON like:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

Then `foo` is always `null`. However, if I encapsulate it in a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And change the action method to:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Foo foo)
```

Then, the JSON is bound properly and `foo.Foo` will be "Bar". How can I forgo wrapping the simple string param in a class, just to get the JSON to bind correctly?

Comment: Well, `dynamic` works in the sense that I don't need to literally create a special class, but it's worse in many ways, as 1) the API is no longer self-documenting (i.e. what actual type *should* that be) and 2) I have to coerce the posted value into the right type manually.

Comment: This above wouldn't work when you want to post back more than one value, because `[FromBody]` attribute can only be used once, as it results in the input stream being read and a network connection can only be read once. If you want the above to work, you'd need to send the post request with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `foo=bar&zoo=baz`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are against deserializing a JSON object to a C# object? Because, that's exactly what it's designed to do.

Comment: @Tseng: I don't need to post back more than one value. That's sort of the point.

Comment: @MindingData: I'm not against deserializing a JSON object. I have other actions where I'm doing exactly that, as they actually take class-type params. However, here, my action only requires a single string, and it feels ridiculous to have to create a class wrapper with a single string property, simply to accept JSON.

Comment: Well, `"foo"` is valid json too which can be serialized from and to a string, which is why sending `"foo"` to the action will serialize to the string parameter too. You can also see the spec for it: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 "A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it allows binding to one or many primitive types and class object at the same time from json data. Warning: It seems to work OK so far but not well tested, use this more as a template than a full solution. Only annoying thing is you still need to set the [FromBody] on each parameter, not sure how to get around this.

First I create a custom InputFormatter, the **ReadRequestBodyAsync** is called for each parameter, and Newtonsoft.JSON is used to deserialize into a dictionary if basic type and into the actual object if not.

```
  public class CustomJsonImportFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public CustomJsonImportFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public override Boolean CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;

        if (contentType == "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        {
            string jsonBody = context.HttpContext.Items["JsonBody"] as string;

            if(jsonBody == null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
                {
                     jsonBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    context.HttpContext.Items["JsonBody"] = jsonBody;
                }
            }

            bool isBasicType = context.ModelType.IsPrimitive
                    || context.ModelType.Name == "String";

            object value = null;

            if (isBasicType)
            {
                var valueDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBody);
                value = valueDictionary[context.Metadata.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonBody, context.ModelType);
            }                

            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(value);         
        }
        else
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
      }
    }
```

Next you need to configure this in the app start up like so

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(o => { 

o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new CustomJsonImportFormatter());  });
```